# Go "permission denied" when trying to create a file in a newly created directory?

Tags: go, file-permissions

I'm trying to create a directory using `os.Mkdir()` and then create files in it, similar to this script:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    dir := "test_dir"

    os.Mkdir(dir, os.ModeDir)

    fileName := path.Join(dir, "file.txt")

    _, err := os.Create(fileName)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("create file: %v", err)
    }
}
```

However, if I run this, I get

```
> go run fileperms.go
2019/10/15 14:44:02 create file: open test_dir/file.txt: permission denied
exit status 1
```

It is not immediately clear to me from https://golang.org/pkg/os/#FileMode how to specify the `FileMode` in order to allow the same script to create files in the newly-created directory. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Almost all calls to `os.Mkdir` should pass `0777` as the second argument. You don't need `os.ModeDir` as it's implied by the make-directory function. The low 3 bits are Unix-style permissions; it's up to the OS to translate them to whatever the OS uses. On Unix-like systems, the current umask will take away any unwanted permissions, so you should usually grant all permissions to everyone to start.

Comment: Exceptions to this rule include, e.g., a mail message handler, where you might assume user-level privacy and use mode `0700`: rwx for user, nothing for group or other. A typical umask is `002` or `022`, to take away other, and maybe group, write permission.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I found that I am able to create files in the directory if I set the permission to `0777`:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "os"
    "path"
)

func main() {
    dir := "test_dir"

    os.Mkdir(dir, 0777)

    fileName := path.Join(dir, "file.txt")

    ioutil.WriteFile(fileName, []byte("foobar"), 0666)
}
```

Now the file is created with the expected content:

```
> cat test_dir/file.txt 
foobar⏎
```

Comment: after hours of searching and trial error, this one truely solved my problem!
PS: I was using `662`, `420`, `666`, `777`, but none of them worked, especially for `directories`

Comment: there is no case you need to use 777 as it is wide permission. it is considered not secure. please check this link https://superuser.com/questions/1034079/is-it-safe-to-chmod-777-everything

Comment: @YasserSinjab I agree that 777 doesn't sound like a good idea, but I'm facing the same issue and so far 0777 seems to be the only thing that's working. Do you have any other approaches you could suggest?

Answer (score 4):

Here, Go was trying to create inside /tmp directory during an AUR package installation.

So I've changed the permissions in /tmp:

```
chmod 0777 -R /tmp
```

But that was not enough, so I had to change /tmp ownership (it was root's):

```
sudo chown -R "$USER":wheel /tmp
```